bitrix настройка роутинга
почему не работает роутинг в bitrix?
я добавил в файл .htaccess следующие строчки:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/routing_index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/routing_index.php [L]

добавил в .settings.php
'routing' => ['value' => [
        'config' => ['api.php'],
    ],
        'readonly' => true,
        ],

создал /local/routes/api.php с следующим кодом:
<?php
use Bitrix\Main\Routing\RoutingConfigurator;

return function (RoutingConfigurator $routes) {
    $routes->get('/projects', function (){
        return "123";
    });
};

но при переходе по адресу http://localhost/projects я получаю ошибку 404

В каком окружении у вас все это запускается (веб-сервер, PHP)? Возможно файл .htaccess  не обрабатывается и правила нужно менять в другом месте.
